# Get the array of filenames stored in document directory in React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-fetch-blob

**CASE**

I have downloaded audio files to my document directory under the folder named /tracks/ as :

```
RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DocumentDir + '/tracks/'
```

No doubt I can read each audio by their name as :

```
RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DocumentDir + '/tracks/' + 'audio1.mp3'
```

**QUESTION:**
I want to get the list of all the audios.
I can see in File Access API , we can read file but I am unable to find how to get the list of audio files from the folder '/tracks/'.

I just want to have an array of filenames in that directory.

***File Access API link :*** 
https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob/wiki/File-System-Access-API#dirs

P.S: I didn't want to go for other file access plugins.
I don't know if I have to search other libraries for file listing .

**UPDATE**

With the following code:

```
var TRACK_FOLDER = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DocumentDir + '/tracks/';

console.log('Files LIST in Tracks Folder = ', RNFetchBlob.fs.ls(TRACK_FOLDER));
```

OUTPUT IS :

[image: Screenshot of Google console]

I think I'm getting close but's output seems difficult to parse.
:(

FINALLY:(this is the way how it is done)

```
    var TRACK_FOLDER = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DocumentDir + '/tracks/';

    console.log('Files list in TRACK_FOLDER = ', RNFetchBlob.fs.ls(TRACK_FOLDER));

     RNFetchBlob.fs.ls(TRACK_FOLDER)
    .then( (files) =>{ 
        console.log(files.length);  
        console.log(files); 
        console.log(files[0]); 

    })
```

OUTPUT: 
[image: final output]

Hope this helps somebody out there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`RNFetchBlob.fs.ls` returns a promise.

So you can either access it with using `.then/.catch`

```
RNFetchBlob.fs.ls(TRACK_FOLDER).then(files => {
  console.log(files);
}).catch(error => console.log(error))
```

or you can use `async/await`

```
try {
  let files = await RNFetchBlob.fs.ls(TRACK_FOLDER);
  console.log(files);
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

You can read more about `RNFetchBlob.fs.ls` [here](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob/wiki/File-System-Access-API#lspathstringpromisearray). Also note that the repository for RNFetchBlob has moved to here https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob

Comment: yep it returns a promise .
anyway thanks @Andrew for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I used lstat which returns all files include following:

```
{
filename: "RNPM_2238640396305543067.png"
lastModified: "1632219571000"
path: "/data/user/0/com.test.app/cache/RNPM_2238640396305543067.png"
size: "21059"
type: "file"
}
```