# React Native - Get file name from android content uri

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-fs

I need to get file name from android content uri, for example:

content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/15


I try to used react-native-fs stat but it return error of "File does not exist".

How can I do it?

Comment: That is not a file. In standard Java/Kotlin Android, you might use `DocumentFile.fromSingleUri()` and the `getName()` function to get a "display name" associated with the content identified by the `Uri`. I do not know if anyone has created a React Native wrapper for that.

Comment: In java you would query the content resolver for DISPLAY_NAME like getContentResolver().query(uri) and then use the returned cursor for column DISPLAY_NAME. Please translate to react-native.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I not found pure solution in react native, so I created native package in android and created module in react native from so I can use it.

This the the android code:

```
@ReactMethod
    public void getFileNameFromUri(String filepath, Promise promise) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(filepath);
        String fileName = "";

        if (uri.getScheme().equals("content")) {
            try {
                Cursor cursor = reactContext.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);

                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    fileName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    Log.d("FS", "Real File name: " + fileName);
                }
                cursor.close();
                promise.resolve(fileName);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException ignored) {
                promise.reject("1", "Can not get cursor");
            }
        } else {
            promise.resolve(fileName);
        }
    }
```

This is how to module in react native from android native code:
 [react-native-modules-android](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android)

Comment: That's great. I personally aim to find solutions built for react-native that support Android and iOS. Have you tried https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob ? Also a stackoverflow answer using rn-fetch-blob https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54743482/get-the-array-of-filenames-stored-in-document-directory-in-react-native

Comment: @Alex no but I read on it, and it work like reat-native-fs to get the file real path. Like I understand there is no way to get the real file path in android. Also in IOS is very easy to get the file name because you get the real file path with file:// so just need to cut the file name from the path.

Answer (score 1):

maybe:

```
let filename = uri.substring(uri.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, uri.length)
```